# understanding for loops w/ ranges in python

Tags: python

I don't understand loops w/ranges..

...in light of the answer to problem 1, problem 2 is confusing...

Problem 1:
What is the value of j at the end of the following code segment?

```
j = 0
for i in range(0, 4):
   j = j + i
```

Problem 2:

```
j = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
   if j < 10 :
      j = j + i
```

Problem 1:
Answer: 6
j = (j+1)+(j+2)+(j+3)

Problem 2:
Answer: 10
My answer: ???
Why not j = (j+1)+(j+2)...(j+9)?
(I don't understand what the expression "if j<10" evaluates to here..)

Comment: Have you tried simply executing the code to find out? Or is your question why is the value what it is?

Comment: Correct, why is the value what it is? I have run the code to see what the answer is, and tried inserting different values for i and j to teach myself what the "rule" is, but it doesn't help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
j = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
   if j < 10 :
      j = j + i
```

The outer "for" loop executes until it exhausts the range for i.
On each outer loop, j is evaluated to see if it's less than 10. If it is, j is incremented up by the value of i on that loop. In the 4th loop, j becomes 10 and remains that value for the rest of the execution.

```
loop        j    i   j(end)
1           0    1   1
2           1    2   3
3           3    3   6
4           6    4   10
5           10   5   10
6           10   6   10
7           10   7   10
8           10   8   10
9           10   9   10
<end>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misconception about the order of execution. Every iteration of the loop the statement `if j < 10 :` is evaluated. So after the 4th iteration j does not get increased due to the `if` statement being false.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple logical question. In Problem 2, `j =j + i` is only executed if `j < 10`:

---

After the first run, we have j = (j+1) = 1 (since j is initially 0)
After the second run, we have j = (j+1) + (j+2) = 3
After the fourth run, we have j = (j+1) + (j+2) + (j+3) + (j+4) = 10

---

Since j is no longer less than 10, the `if` condition means that no further `i` is added to j, at this point.

Answer (score 1):

`if j < 10` checks the value of `j` each loop, and runs the following line only if the value of `j` is less than 10. If the value of `j` is equal to or greater than 10, `j = j +  i` is not ran, and the value of `j` is not increased.